# How to read data from XLSX file having data from more than 256 columns

Tags: perl, parsing, cpan, xlsx

How to read data from `XLSX` file having data from more than 256 columns

Tried using `Spreadsheet::XLSX` cpan perl library module but not getting success if we try to read `XLSX` file containing data in 400+ columns (more than 256 columns).

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

I created an XLSX file with Excel 2010 with `1` to `403` in the first row and put that in the example code for Spreadsheet::XLSX. It works:

```
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX->new( 'Mappe3.xlsx', );

foreach my $sheet ( @{ $excel->{Worksheet} } ) {
  printf( "Sheet: %s\n", $sheet->{Name} );
  $sheet->{MaxRow} ||= $sheet->{MinRow};
  foreach my $row ( $sheet->{MinRow} .. $sheet->{MaxRow} ) {
    $sheet->{MaxCol} ||= $sheet->{MinCol};
    foreach my $col ( $sheet->{MinCol} .. $sheet->{MaxCol} ) {
      my $cell = $sheet->{Cells}[$row][$col];
      if ($cell) {
        printf( "( %s , %s ) => %s\n", $row, $col, $cell->{Val} );
      }
    }
  }
}

__END__

Sheet: Tabelle1
( 0 , 0 ) => 1
( 0 , 1 ) => 2
( 0 , 2 ) => 3
[..] # snipped
( 0 , 252 ) => 253
( 0 , 253 ) => 254
( 0 , 254 ) => 255
( 0 , 255 ) => 256
( 0 , 256 ) => 257
[..] # snipped
( 0 , 398 ) => 399
( 0 , 399 ) => 400
( 0 , 400 ) => 401
( 0 , 401 ) => 402
( 0 , 402 ) => 403
Sheet: Tabelle2
Sheet: Tabelle3
```

You should post the code you are using and the error message you are seeing. Otherwise we cannot reproduce the problem.